# Get the information from the tabular layout on button click in oracle forms

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracleforms

Let's say I have table named **Customer** with **NAME** **SURNAME**. I create data block :CUSTOMER from table **CUSTOMER**, and add extra button [show info]
for the layout I select tabular view, and fill the information using default_where and execute statements. so now it appears like this:

```
| NAME | SURNAME |
--------------------------------------------
| ANNA | SMITH   | [Show Info]
| John | Galt    | [Show Info]
.
.
.
```

So on button click I would like to do some operations using the data from the table, for example may be use some query like

```
SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER_HISTORY WHERE NAME = 'ANNA'
```

if I pressed the button [Show Info] from the ANNA's row?

PS. I know query from above makes no sense, just an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create `WHEN-BUTTON-PRESSED` on your button. Important note - set Mouse navigable property on button to True to navigate to right record before trigger starts.

Now you can reference any record value using colon_

```
SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER_HISTORY WHERE NAME = :CUSTOMER.NAME
```

Comment: Looks like magic to me, I came to forms recently, and still have other type of mind i guess. Is it possible to explain, how the button knows which row of the table the button was pressed from?

Comment: When you reference an item like `:CUSTOMER.NAME`, you always get value from ACTUAL record in Customer block. When you set Mouse Navigable property on a button, run form and press the button, forms first navigate (moves cursor) to the button instance you pressed. It means when you press button in third record, cursor navigates do the button AND to the third record - this record becomes ACTUAL. After that fires `WHEN-BUTTON-PRESSED` trigger.